Converting Big INT values to Decimal
I have 2 columns in my incoming database (from another source) that are defined as BIGINT: -111021037 and 32409460. These values are latitude and longitude and should be decimal: -111.021037 and 32.409460.
I'm trying to convert them but am running into issues.
When I try to do a CAST from BIGINT to Decimal(10,6), I get an error:

(CAST(-111021037 AS DECIMAL(10,6)) AS Correct_Lon:  "Arithmetic overflow error converting bigint to data type numeric".

I then changed it to (CAST(-111021037 AS DECIMAL(15,6)) which didn't throw an error, but the result was = -111021037.000000 which is still wrong.
I using SQL Server 2019.

You're half way there - just divide the previous result by a million (to get the decimal point in the correct spot) then re-CAST to the appropriate decimal type e.g., CAST((CAST(-111021037 AS DECIMAL(15,6)) / 1000000) AS DECIMAL(10,6))

How would SQL Server know where to add the decimal point for you when casting? You kinda have to help it with that bit :)

DECIMAL(10,6) in SQL Server means: 10 digits overall, 6 of which after the decimal point (and thus 4 before it) - and that's clearly not enough digits for your values that are incoming.

Thank you!  that will work.  Curious, does the million have to do with it being a lat/long value?
